# Post and Get not mapped to Spring boot - status : 404

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a simple application to test Spring Boot.
Below is the configuration and the packages are set as per Spring documentation.
There is no error in application startup. Using Spring boot with eclipse.
Still the controller is not mapped to the server and when I do Post or Get it says :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1547026379146,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/postdata"
}
```

**Repository:**

```
package com.abc.nice.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.abc.nice.entity.Messages;



@Repository
public interface MessagesRepository extends JpaRepository<Messages, Long> {

}
```

**Entity:**

```
package com.abc.nice.entity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;



@Entity
@Table(name = "Messages")
public class Messages{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@Size(max = 100)
private String toNumber; 


@Size(max = 250)
private String hsm; 

@Size(max = 250)
private String template; 

@Size(max = 250)
private String parameters; 



public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTo() {
    return toNumber;
}

public void setTo(String toNumber) {
    this.toNumber = toNumber;
}

public String getHsm() {
    return hsm;
}

public void setHsm(String hsm) {
    this.hsm = hsm;
}

public String getTemplate() {
    return template;
}

public void setTemplate(String template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public String getParameters() {
    return parameters;
}

public void setParameters(String parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
}



}
```

**Controller :**

```
package com.abc.nice.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.abc.nice.entity.Messages;
import com.abc.nice.repo.MessagesRepository;

@RestController
public class ControllerRest {

    @Autowired
    private Messages msgDao;
    private MessagesRepository msgRepo;


    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping({ "/StatusData" })
    public List<Messages> index() {
        return this.msgRepo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = {"/postdata"})
    public ResponseEntity<Messages> createBody(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        this.msgDao = new Messages();
        this.msgDao.setTemplate((String) body.get("template"));
        this.msgDao.setParameters((String) body.get("parameters"));
        this.msgDao.setHsm((String) body.get("hsm"));
        this.msgDao.setTo((String) body.get("to"));

        return new ResponseEntity<Messages>(this.msgRepo.save(this.msgDao), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**MainClass :**

```
package com.abc.nice;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;








@SpringBootApplication
//@EntityScan("com.abc.nice.entity")
@ComponentScan({"com.abc.nice.entity","com.abc.nice.controller"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.abc.nice.repo"})
//@EnableAutoConfiguration


public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication .class, args);



    }

}
```

**Startup Log :**

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2019-01-09 17:33:27.724  INFO 19732 --- [           main] com.abc.nice.TestApplication : Starting TestApplication on abcD02 with PID 19732 (C:\Users\abcd\Desktop\test\target\classes started by abcD in C:\Users\abcd\Desktop\test)
2019-01-09 17:33:27.728  INFO 19732 --- [           main] com.abc.nice.TestApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-09 17:33:27.827  INFO 19732 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4206a205: startup date [Wed Jan 09 17:33:27 SGT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-09 17:33:29.489  INFO 19732 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-01-09 17:33:29.506  INFO 19732 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-09 17:33:29.507  INFO 19732 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2019-01-09 17:33:29.746  INFO 19732 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-09 17:33:29.746  INFO 19732 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1922 ms
2019-01-09 17:33:30.005  INFO 19732 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2019-01-09 17:33:30.009  INFO 19732 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-09 17:33:30.009  INFO 19732 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-09 17:33:30.009  INFO 19732 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-09 17:33:30.009  INFO 19732 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-01-09 17:33:30.598  INFO 19732 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-09 17:33:30.610  INFO 19732 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-01-09 17:33:30.680  INFO 19732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2019-01-09 17:33:30.682  INFO 19732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-01-09 17:33:30.683  INFO 19732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-01-09 17:33:30.749  INFO 19732 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-01-09 17:33:30.864  INFO 19732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-01-09 17:33:31.033  INFO 19732 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2019-01-09 17:33:31.058  INFO 19732 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-09 17:33:31.388  INFO 19732 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4206a205: startup date [Wed Jan 09 17:33:27 SGT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-09 17:33:31.454  INFO 19732 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-01-09 17:33:31.455  INFO 19732 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-01-09 17:33:31.489  INFO 19732 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-01-09 17:33:31.489  INFO 19732 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-01-09 17:33:31.527  INFO 19732 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-01-09 17:33:31.866  INFO 19732 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-01-09 17:33:31.937  INFO 19732 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-01-09 17:33:31.942  INFO 19732 --- [           main] com.abc.nice.WhatsapptestApplication     : Started WhatsapptestApplication in 4.532 seconds (JVM running for 6.213)
2019-01-09 17:39:45.612  INFO 19732 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
2019-01-09 17:39:45.613  INFO 19732 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4206a205: startup date [Wed Jan 09 17:33:27 SGT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-09 17:39:45.616  INFO 19732 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-01-09 17:39:45.617  INFO 19732 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

**Application.properties:**

```
#spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ptpreconn?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Comment: add your application.properties

Comment: what about get `/WhatsAppStatusData`? Does that work?

Comment: just simply use `@GetMapping( "/WhatsAppStatusData" )` without `{}` and check. I never used in my project.

Comment: do you have something like `server.servlet.context-path: /api` in your `application.yml`?

Comment: No i dont have context path set

Comment: what is the exact url that you use for request?

Comment: This seems like an issue with component scanning. After looking at your startup log, there is no line where it says that your controller was mapped as a handler for `/postdata`. Could you please add a `@PostConstruct` method in your controller? Which just logs something into the console. That way we can see if it's in fact loaded

Comment: I dont think this is the right way to inject multiple beans in your controller...

   ` @Autowired
    private Messages msgDao;
    private MessagesRepository msgRepo;`

You need:
 `   @Autowired
    private Messages msgDao; 
   @Autowired
    private MessagesRepository msgRepo;`

Comment: There's nothing built-in to the language that allows that kind of multi-annotations.

i.e @Autowired private Messages msgDao; private MessagesRepository msgRepo; in your Controller class.

Comment: @AmosKosgei doesn't work, same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please attach request from e.g. the developers' tools with HTTP verb that you are using and exact response from that request. I am concerned about @GetMapping - why it is in curly braces? 
About post mapping, maybe you should describe consumes and produces part of mapping?
E.g.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/members", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

I have never used @PostMapping annotation without those parts.

UPDATE:

After removal of unnecessary component scan in Main class change controller as follow:

```
@RestController
public class ControllerRest {

    @Autowired
    private MessagesRepository msgRepo;

    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping({ "/StatusData" })
    public List<Messages> index() {
        return this.msgRepo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = {"/postdata"})
    public ResponseEntity<Messages> createBody(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        Messages  msgDao = new Messages();
        msgDao.setTemplate((String) body.get("template"));
        msgDao.setParameters((String) body.get("parameters"));
        msgDao.setHsm((String) body.get("hsm"));
        msgDao.setTo((String) body.get("to"));

        return new ResponseEntity<Messages>(this.msgRepo.save(this.HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue after this change In Logs i dont see the get and post mapped. also postman throws 404

Comment: @enemyofnone are you sure you are sending a `application/json` request? can you post the content of the request?

Comment: curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/postdata \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 98b7a597-7844-4620-b149-ecb3bf339193' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{"messages": [{"to":"+911111234","hsm":{"template": "welcome_notification_demo","parameters":{"1": "abc","2":"test"}}}]}'

Comment: @EstebanMarin also added application.properties

Comment: Startup log ends with a shutdown. You have copied log from whole execution? Maybe the application is not started at all

Comment: I shut it down mistakenly copied last 3 lines

Comment: This line is unnecessary for sure.
@ComponentScan({"com.abc.nice.entity","com.abc.nice.controller"})

Comment: @MichałMarcinkowski without component scan it throws below error:

Field msgDao in com.abc.nice.controller.ControllerRest required a bean of type 'com.abc.nice.entity.Messages' that could not be found.

Comment: Thats right. Because you wrongly use Messages class. Messages is Entity class and it should not be autowired but created on runtime in createBody method. Remove Autowired messages and build Messages object from createBody method argument. This will do the trick.

Comment: @MichałMarcinkowski ur updated code for controller class worked. thanks

Comment: @enemyofone No problem. If it solves the problem then please mark the answer as approved : )

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a context path to your application.properties file or application.yml, whichever you are using.

   `server.servlet.contextPath=/springbootapi`
2. Hit your endpoint: The endpoint for your POST method will be:

   http://localhost:{PORT}/springbootapi/postdata
3. Why dont you statically supply your port. I think the port should be something like:
   `server.port=8080`

Comment: There is no need to supply port. It by default starts on 8080 port. It should also start up on default context normally

Comment: Tried both the suggestions, also removed server.port property, None worked :(

Comment: I dont think your Controller Bean is being loaded by the context.

Add     @Autowired above ` private MessagesRepository msgRepo;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you using @RequestBody with `"Map<String,String>".`

Try this code :

```
@Autowired
private MessagesRepository msgRepo;

 @PostMapping("/postdata")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createBody(@RequestBody Message message) {
    Message saveMessage= msgRepo.save(message);

URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
        .buildAndExpand(saveMessage.getId()).toUri();

return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

Comment: No Luck, the problem is that in logs i dont see any POST or GET being mapped

Comment: You can post your pom ?

Comment: I think if POST or GET map code not run. And variable restTemplate ? . I can't find it from your code ?